# Access namespaced JS functions via autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, function, autocomplete, namespaces

I am using pretty "vanilla" Eclipse on Mac with Aptana plugin.

if I were to write:

```
function blah() {}
```

And then hit CTRL+space, I will see "blah" on the autocomplete list.

However realistically, I never write methods like that. I write:

```
MyNamespace.methodName = function() {}
```

I would like hit CTRL+space and have "MyNamespace.methodName" appear in the autocomplete list. Is this possible? I don't want to switch IDEs but I will add plugins if it helps.